# How to assign a field in object list with a corresponding item from another using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say that I have a `List<MyClass> myObjects` and I have `int[] numbers`. Given that:

1. Length of `numbers` equals the `mObjects.Count`.
2. I'm using a class that has some other fields and methods like this:

   ```
   class MyClass
   {
       public int Number;
       public int AnotherNumber;
       public void WorkWithNumber() { /* Do some work. */ }
   }
   ```

Is there a way using linq to assign each item of `numbers` to a corresponding `MyClass.Number` in the list? Perferably using `myObjects.ForEach()`.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `myObjects.ForEach()` instead of a `for` loop with an integer index that you can use to get values in `numbers`?

Comment: @mbadawi23 How do you correspond the integer value in `numbers` with the object in `myObjects`?

Comment: Can't you just iterate through `numbers` and do that?

Comment: @DanWilson I understand that I could use `for` or `foreach` to do this, but I was hoping for a linq solution similar to `Zip`.

Comment: I understand. I was just curious why you wanted to use LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use LINQ, there is overload of Select that takes lambda with two arguments: object and its index:

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new []{1,2,3,4,5};

        var objects = new []{new Obj(),new Obj(),new Obj(),new Obj(),new Obj()};

        objects = objects.Select((x,i)=>{
            x.Int = list[i];

            return x;
        }).ToArray();

        foreach(var o in objects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o.Int);
        }

    }
    }

public class Obj 
{
    public int Int {get;set;}
}
```

You need to call ToArray() so that LINQ is evaluated, but assigment back to objects variable is not necessairy

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should do it with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var p in myList.Select((obj, idx) => new { Val = numbers[idx], Obj = obj })) {
    p.Obj.Number = p.Val;
}
```

You could use the same trick without `foreach`, but the solution would be a lot less readable.

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ algorithm for iterating synchronously over two lists is **`Enumerable.Zip`**.

But this won't work unless you evaluate the result of the expression because

1. your requirement is non functional programming because of the side effect of modifying the existing items in the second list,
2. LINQ uses deferred execution and no side effect will ever apply unless the expression is evaluated.

You can avoid this pitfall by applying `.ToList()` and discard the result:

```
numbers.Zip(myObjects, (i, obj) => obj.Number = i).ToList();
```

But this it is not that pretty.

1. because you create a result list just for the purpose to be discarded.
2. because it will sadly fail in case of a value type.

---

Another option is to add a **non functional overload of `.Zip`**. I.e.:

```
public static class EnumerableX
{ public static void Zip<T1,T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> list1, IEnumerable<T2> list2, Action<T1,T2> act)
  { using (var en1 = list1.GetEnumerator())
    using (var en2 = list2.GetEnumerator())
      while (en1.MoveNext() & en2.MoveNext())
        act(en1.Current, en2.Current);
  }
}
```

With this extension **the following line will do the job**:

```
numbers.Zip(myObjects, (i, obj) => { obj.Number = i; });
```

But the problem with value types resides. To overcome this the parameter to the `Action` need to by of type `ref T1`. But this is significantly more work and not in the scope of *this* question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a for loop over `myObjects` and assign the `Number` property from the corresponding index in `numbers`.

```
void Main()
{
    var myObjects = new List<MyClass>();
    myObjects.Add(new MyClass());
    myObjects.Add(new MyClass());
    myObjects.Add(new MyClass());

    var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    for(var i = 0; i < myObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        myObjects.ElementAt(i).Number = numbers[i];
        Console.WriteLine($"myObjects.ElementAt(i).Number = {myObjects.ElementAt(i).Number}");
    }

    //  myObjects.ElementAt(i).Number = 1
    //  myObjects.ElementAt(i).Number = 2
    //  myObjects.ElementAt(i).Number = 3
}

class MyClass
{
    public int Number;
    public int AnotherNumber;
    public void WorkWithNumber() { /* Do some work. */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
//Set things up...
List<MyClass> myObjects = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass{Number = 23},
    new MyClass{Number = 42},
    new MyClass{Number = 66}
};
int [] numbers = new int[myObjects.Count];

//answer your question...
var i = 0;
foreach (var myObj in myObjects)
{
    numbers[i] = myObj.Number;
    ++i;
}
```

You can loop over two collections with "for", but "foreach" works with a single collection (unless there's a language feature that I don't know about).

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the [overload to `Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) that passes you an index:

```
numbers.Select((item, index) => myObjects[index].Number = item)
       .ToList();
```

The con of this approach is that you have the overhead of invoking `ToList/ToArray` in order to force execution of the `Select`. You could write your own extension method that iterates the enumerable and does nothing:

```
public static class MyEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForceExecute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        foreach (T item in source);
    }
}
```

...then:

```
numbers.Select((item, index) => myObjects[index].Number = item)
       .ForceExecute();
```

...though doing so may be less than intuitive for your fellow programmers.